# whats wrong in this query its not deleting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, csv

I am using `echo $fss` its display data

> "11-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V5703211-V57032"

but i am using delete query using this variable but its not working

```
<?php  

 //connect to the database 
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
 mysql_select_db("cityshoes",$connect); //select the table 


if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 



    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 

 $fss = addslashes($data[1]);
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno = . $fss . ");

        echo $fss;


        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 



} 

?>
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending variable in the query in wrong way. Try with:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno = $fss");
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE from contacts where articleno ='".$fss ."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn this line

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno = . $fss . ");
```

To this

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno =  $fss ");
```

You have to remove the periods.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno =  $fss "); i changes to it but still not deleting  any thing wrong in do while loop

Comment: Have you paste that sql command into phpmyadmin and replaced $fss with sample code to test to make sure the string works?